# C++ if-Statement Malfuncton

Tags: c++, if-statement, case-sensitive

If I enter Artist I will get the if from the Artist plus the else statement too. I cant see what the problem is it compiles fine but only on capital letter Artist it gives me double value on artist all is good.

```
cin >> answer;

if (answer == "Artist") {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 6);
    cout << "Playing music like a boss" << endl;
    Drums = (Drums + 1);
    Base = (Base + 1);

}
if (answer == "artist") {

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 6);
    cout << "Playing music like a boss" << endl;
    Drums = (Drums + 1);
    Base = (Base + 1);
}
else {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 2);
    cout << "You should buy a guitar" << endl;
    Drums = (Drums + 1);
    Bag = (Bag - 1);
}
```

**[EDIT]** Okay, I changed the code to using if statements but the problem remains.

Comment: How does this compile for you?

Comment: Now that I changed it to if statements and also used || thanks to Seth's advice it works good. Also deleted the second if and it no longer causes bug.

Comment: @Sinner: One of the most important things about C++ is the types. What is the type of answer. If it is a std::string this will work but if it is a C-String it will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use strings in `switch` statements. Only integral constants can be used in `switch`. You'll have to use a series of `if` statements.

Comment: Well you can (with C-String) but it will not do what you want because it is comparing the address rather than the string.

Comment: @LokiAstari yeah, it's using the address as the integral value to compare with. So technically nothing's stopping you, but it probably won't do what you want it to do, so you're right.

Comment: I just edited the code to if statements but I still get the same problem it parses the if of the capital letter starting one and the else also. when i enter artist it works perfect. only on Artist it gives dual values.

Comment: @Sinner change your first `if` to `if (answer == "Artist" || answer == "artist")` and remove the second `if` and its contents, and leave the `else`. This will do one thing if the string is either `artist` or `Artist`, and the `else` if it's not.

Comment: Oh I had no idea this was possible so the double || separates more casses of the cin for the first if?? (im begineer with C++ so i appreciate all your help very much!!

Comment: @Sinner yes, you can seperate conditions with `||` and that means "or". You can also use `&&` to mean "and". So `if (a && b || c)` means "if a and also b, or c". The `||` and `&&` have low precedence, but of the two, `||` has lower precedence than `&&`, so that means `if (a && b || c)` is like `if ((a && b) || c)`

Answer (score 2):

The way it is now, if the string contains "Artist" then you will execute that block, fail the check for "artist" and execute the else block.

You most likely want:

```
else if (answer == "artist") {
```

This will make it so only one of the block will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

How does this work? You cannot switch on a string, you have to use string equality to check.

A [switch statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement) compiles down to a jump table, where the input is essentially choosing which target in the jump table is taken. So your switch input has to be of an integral type. Not a string.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not my strongest language, but my understanding that using switch with a String has undefined behavior.